# Selecting a text which is not "spanned"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to retrieve data on pages.
I can't change the markup. Only have the console to work with.

```
<div class="dataContainer" style="display: block;">
 <h4>titre</h4>
 <b>Type:</b> Affiliate<br>
 <b>Location:</b> 400 Jackson Boulevard,  Los Angeles, CA, 90002<br>
 <b>Phone:</b> (xxx) yyy-zzzz <br>
 <b>Fax:</b> (xxx) yyy-zzzz  <br>
 <b>Contact Person:</b> John Doe<br>
 <b>Email Address:</b> <a href="mailto:john@doe.edu">john@doe.edu</a><br>
 <b>Website:</b> <a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">http://example.com</a><br>
 <b>Designations:</b> job title
</div>
```

To retrieve the contact's name, I tried :

```
var b = jQuery(jQuery('.dataContainer').children('b:contains(Contact)').nextSibling);
alert(b.text());
```

How to select the strings after the `</b>` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.children()` returns a jQuery object, so to call `nextSibling` you need to get the dom element reference

```js
var b = jQuery(jQuery('.dataContainer').children('b:contains(Contact)')[0].nextSibling);
alert(b.text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dataContainer" style="display: block;">
  <h4>titre</h4>
  <b>Type:</b> Affiliate
  <br>
  <b>Location:</b> 400 Jackson Boulevard, Los Angeles, CA, 90002
  <br>
  <b>Phone:</b> (xxx) yyy-zzzz
  <br>
  <b>Fax:</b> (xxx) yyy-zzzz
  <br>
  <b>Contact Person:</b> John Doe
  <br>
  <b>Email Address:</b>  <a href="mailto:john@doe.edu">john@doe.edu</a>
  <br>
  <b>Website:</b>  <a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">http://example.com</a>
  <br>
  <b>Designations:</b> job title
</div>
```

Comment: Works Great Arun, Thx ! 
Any documentation I can refer to, to better understand the underlying concept of jQuery object ? I believe that _children_ is a jquery function, whereas _nextSibling_ is a core javascript method, so is this [0] related to some _conversion_ from jquery to javascript ?

Comment: is [0] the same as get(0) ?

Comment: @AdrienLafond yes.. they are the same

Comment: @AdrienLafond I think you can start with http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/